# how to reset skype?

Tags: skype

How can I reset my skype configuration?

I think this could be done by removing or modifying its configuration folder. Will this work and where is it?

Comment: Skype settings are usually in `.Skype`, a hidden folder in /home/username.

Comment: Can you be a little more specific?

Answer (score 0):

The entire user-specific configuration of Skype is located in the directory `~/.Skype` (`~` represents your current user's home directory).

You can safely delete it to reset the configuration.

To do recursively delete this folder, open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and enter the command:

```
rm -r ~/.Skype
```

If you are not 100% sure and prefer to just rename (here: to `.Skype-backup`) it in case you want it back later, run this instead:

```
mv .Skype .Skype-backup
```

You can also perform that using your GUI file manager (usually `nautilus`). Just make sure you have enabled it to show hidden files (names starting with a `.`). Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> or click on the menu **View** > **Show hidden files**.